# how to Insert an English table into a persian text written by the use of xepersian package

Tags: tables, xepersian

I am writing a in `\documentclass{report}` and I use `\usepackage{xepersian}`. In a separate `.tex` file I created a table which is written in English. 
I want to put this table in my text using `\include` but since I use the `xepersian`package all the words in my table appear as some squares!
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The `xepersian` package provides a `latin` environment, so you can input the table inside that environment:

```
\begin{latin}
\input{table}
\end{latin}
```